# Do I have to write a decentralized application in the same language as the blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

Do I have to write a decentralized application in the same language as the blockchain?

Comment: From my understanding you cannot use any random language to write a dApp, you need to use the language the corresponding blockchain defines for such apps. But this language does not need to be the language the miners run on, the miner software only needs to include an implementation of the dApp language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, each language has it's own bytecodes to compile to, and each blockchain supports different bytecodes. However, if you mean the frontend application, such as the website, for the dApp, then no.